# Let X be the set of reals with the finite-complement topology. Find all subsets of X that are both open and closed

Tags: general-topology

We let $X$ have the finite-complement topology and let $A \subseteq X$. I assume $A$ is both open and closed in $X$ and I want to show $A$ must either be $\emptyset$ or $X$. If $A$ is open in $X$ then $X-A$ must be finite or all of $X$ and if $A$ is closed in $X$ then $X-A$ is open in X. So $X-A$ must be finite or all of $X$ and must open be at the same time. How do I then show A must be either be $X$ or $\emptyset$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. If $X - A$ is open then $X - (X - A) = A$ is finite or equal to $X$. But if $A \neq \emptyset$ is finite, then you can show that $A$ is not open.